# Invalid xml with RestSharp

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-mvc-5, linkedin-api, restsharp

When I share my post in linkedIn through Api using `RestSharp` , it shows me the error

`Invalid xml {Expected elements 'post-network-update@...........'`

```
    public class LinkedInPost(string title, string description, string url, string imageUrl=null)
    {
       ApiBaseUrl111 = LLinkedInBaseUrllll;
        var request = new RestRequest("v1/people/~/shares?format=json", Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + Token);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        request.AddHeader("x-li-format", "json");
        //request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        var model = new class
        {
            Comment = "This is my comment",
        LinkedInContent = new LinkedInContent
            {
                LinkedInDescription = description,
                LinkedInTitle = title,
                Submittedurl = url,
                Submittedimageurl = imageUrl
            },
            LinkedInVisibility = new LinkedInVisibility
                    {
                        LinkedInCode = "anyone"
                    }
        };
        request.AddJsonBody(model);
        var response = Execute<class>(request);
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think this is a RestSharp issue per se. At first I thought it was since I'm getting the same error using RestSharp with LinkedIn. However, I just swapped out RestSharp for HttpWebRequest, and the error persists, so there must be something else going on here.

Comment: i tried this code on another project but its work. may be error in project solution ,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn returns this error when there are missing fields in the posted JSON.

In your case, unless you were using a custom serializer behind the scenes, `LinkedInContent`, `LinkedInVisibility`, etc. likely weren't being serialized to `"content"`, `"visibility"`, etc., which are the JSON fields that LinkedIn is looking for.

In my case, I had spelled `comment` with three M's. :)

Here's the full error for future searches:

```
{  
   "errorCode": 0,
   "message": "Invalid xml {Expected elements &#39;post-network-update@http://api.linkedin.com/v1 id@http://api.linkedin.com/v1 visibility@http://api.linkedin.com/v1 ad-account@http://api.linkedin.com/v1 comment@http://api.linkedin.com/v1 attribution@http://api.linkedin.com/v1 content@http://api.linkedin.com/v1 mention@http://api.linkedin.com/v1 title@http://api.linkedin.com/v1 dsc-name@http://api.linkedin.com/v1 private-message@http://api.linkedin.com/v1 share-target-reach@http://api.linkedin.com/v1&#39; instead of &#39;commment@http://api.linkedin.com/v1&#39; here in element share@http://api.linkedin.com/v1}",
   "requestId": "ODBIHNJYOZ",
   "status": 400,
   "timestamp": 1455664570337
}
```